# Function doesn't return correct TCHAR

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make a function that simply return a TCHAR or a LPCWSTR and i can't handle that, don't know why!

My code looks like:

```
TCHAR MainClass::GetString(){
    if (hWnd == NULL)
        return NULL;

    TCHAR name[256];
    GetWindowText(hWnd, name, 256);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)(name), L"Testing this!", MB_OK);
    return name[256]; 
}
```

If i run this code, it shows a messagebox like i want with the correct message, but the return is a blank string.

If i try to return a LPCWSTR, it returns blank too, what am i doing wrong here?

--
EDIT

```
TCHAR* MainClass::GetString(){
if (hWnd == NULL)
    return NULL;

TCHAR name[256];
GetWindowText(hWnd, name, 256);

return (TCHAR *)malloc(sizeof(name)); 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to return?  A string? or a single character?

Comment: Insisted of `return name[256];` use `return name;` if You want to return a string.

Comment: @KasiyA `use return name` You should not return the address of a local variable.

Comment: @kasiyA: it is not OK to return a pointer to a local variable, though. The variable will go out of scope upon exit before the pointer can be used by the caller.

Comment: @user3649005 - You have jumped from the frying pan and into the fire.  There is no need to introduce malloc(), especially in a C++ program.  You have a wealth of options -- string variables (i.e. `std::wstring`, `std::string`) plus low-tech options such as simply wrapping the array in a struct and returning the struct.

Comment: @user3649005: you made the code worse. Now you are allocating memory, but you are not filling it with anything. You would have to `memcpy()` the contents of `name[]` into it before you `return` it.  This not the way you should be coding in C++. This is how you would code in C instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, @Remy Lebeau:If `TCHAR name[256];` was `static TCHAR name[256];` do it's true?

Comment: @KasiyA: if the variable were `static` then yes, you could return a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> MainClass::GetString()
{
    TCHAR name[256] = {0};
    int len = GetWindowText(hWnd, name, 256);
    return std::basic_string<TCHAR>(name, len); 
}
```

Or this:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> MainClass::GetString()
{
    int len = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    if (len == 0) return std::basic_string<TCHAR>();
    std::vector<TCHAR> name(len+1);
    len = GetWindowText(hWnd, &name[0], name.size());
    return std::basic_string<TCHAR>(&name[0], len); 
}
```

Either way, then you can do this:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> name = GetString();
```

Alternatively:

```
int MainClass::GetString(LPTSTR name, int maxlen)
{
    return GetWindowText(hWnd, name, maxlen);
}
```

```
TCHAR name[256];
int namelen = GetString(name, 256);
```

Comment: Thank you man :) 
Now i'm using this way and it's working perfectly (LPCWSTR)name.c_str()

Comment: @user3649005 - Why are you casting to LPCWSTR?  There should be no casts whatsoever.  Take away the cast -- if you get a compiler error with that cast removed, then it *is not* working perfectly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's working without the LPCWSTR, thank you, i justs noticed that now!

Answer (score 2):

Your function is returning a `TCHAR`, which will be either a single `char` or a single `wchar_t`, depending on whether or not `UNICODE` is defined.

The statement `return name[256]` is returning the single character at offset 256 from the beginning of your `name` array. That means you are returning a single `TCHAR` which is **one past the end of the array**. That is why you are not getting the string that you expect.

You cannot declare an automatic stack variable and return a pointer to it from a function -- it goes out of scope when the function exits.

You probably want to `malloc()` your string, return a `TCHAR*` to it, and then `free()` it in the calling function.

Comment: Just edited my post.


If i put this code, i just get some random characters. Nothing like my string. Any tip?

Comment: @user3649005 The "tip" is to start using C++ and use string classes.

Comment: You did the malloc correctly, but you don't copy the string from GetWindowText to the buffer you allocated with malloc. So you're seeing garbage leftover from memory.